# Why is matrix multiplication faster with Repa than with hmatrix?

Tags: haskell, matrix-multiplication

It's interesting that Data.Array.Repa is actually faster than hmatrix, which is unexpected since hmatrix is implemented using LAPACK. Is this because Repa uses the unboxed type?

```
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Matrix

main = do
    let
        a = fromListUnboxed (Z:.1000:.1000::DIM2) $ replicate (1000*1000) 1.0 :: Array U DIM2 Double
        b = fromListUnboxed (Z:.1000:.1000::DIM2) $ replicate (1000*1000) 1.0 :: Array U DIM2 Double
    m <- (a `mmultP` b)
    print $ m!(Z:.900:.900)
```

running time with 1 core: 7.011s
running time with 2 core: 3.975s

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.LAPACK

main = do
    let
        a = (1000><1000) $ replicate (1000*1000) 1.0
        b = (1000><1000) $ replicate (1000*1000) 1.0
    print $ (a `multiplyR` b) @@> (900,900)
```

Running time: 20.714s

Comment: Have you tried building a proper microbenchmark with Criterion?  It seems like measuring construction and multiplication and IO for printing all in one go is bound to get lots of noise and results that don't connect to any real use case.

Comment: Also, Reps is parallel and LAPACK might not be in this case

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Good suggestion! However, I don't think construction would take too much time in this case, and since I only printed one element in the matrix, IO is not a big deal either. I'll try Criterion when I have time.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `repa`, but is it possible that `repa` is being lazy and not computing the entire matrix?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I don't think so here, because the benchmark uses _unboxed_ repa arrays (`fromListUnboxed` and also the `U` parameter to Array). I think laziness would have kicked in with `Delayed` arrays (`D` parameter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are using a non-optimized LAPACK library. In my computer, using libatlas-base, the running time is ~0.4s.

$ cat matrixproduct.hs

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

main = do
    let a = (1000><1000) $ replicate (1000*1000) (1::Double)
        b = konst 1 (1000,1000)
    print $ a@@>(100,100)
    print $ b@@>(100,100)
    print $ (a <> b) @@> (900,900)
```

$ ghc matrixproduct.hs -O

$ time ./matrixproduct

```
1.0
1.0
1000.0

real    0m0.331s
user    0m0.512s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Comment: You are right! That solves the problem. But I can't find libatlas-base on Centos, while there is one for Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need to do anything to tell hmatrix to use the optimized libraries? I've installed libatlas-base and rebuilt hmatrix and my code, and see no difference in perf.